# How to show multiple Google Maps with different locations created in Advance Custom Fields Wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I have created two Maps fields in Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) Plugin in its field group area, please check the screenshot [image: Advanced Custom Fields Google Map field group]
But on the front end when I try to add the code as per Google Maps custom field code only one Map is showing not the second one https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/

[image: Try to show second Google Map but not working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah yes, I'm able to figure this out. There has no need of any other different settings, just need to add one more field in ACF fields group area and show that field in the front end by doing the same settings as did on the first field but just change the location variable name and pass the second field value in it. Below is the complete code example to show the first and second map in different HTML elements.

First Map:

```
    <?php
                        $location = get_field('map');

                        if( !empty($location) ):
                        ?>
                        <div class="acf-map">
                            <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>"></div>
                        </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Second Map:

```
    <?php
        $location_second = get_field('map_second');
            if( !empty($location_second) ):
    ?>
    <div class="acf-map">
        <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location_second['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location_second['lng']; ?>"></div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

As I have created two map fields in ACF plugin, first map field's name is Map and Second map field name is Map Second, so these will be used as map and map_second in code as given above.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have ACF Pro version :)
then you can use repeater field
Create repeater field "locations" then inside only one field with name "location" and use code from example "Render multiple markers onto a map"

Comment: No, I have the free version of ACF :(

Comment: Ah sorry, I just checked and can see it is pro version. Do you have any example already runing with this repeater field?